# How to use Nested Ternary Operator in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

```
String greeting ='';
Integer Hour = 10;

greeting = ((Hour<12) ?'Good Morning':'Good Afternoon') : ((Hour>12) ?'Good Morning':'Good Afternoon');

system.debug('Ternary Operator-->'+greeting);
```

I want to display Good Morning, if Hour is less than 12,
I want to display Good Afternoon, if Hour is greater than 12,

But I want to use in single nested ternary operator in the apex but getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is just a condensed `if`. You don't need two of them here, since you have only one condition. Just do:

```
greeting = (Hour <= 12) ? 'Good Morning' : 'Good Afternoon';
```